# How can i remove parentheses in scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

i have a function in scheme, this function calls another function many times, and every time this function appends return value of another function to result value.
but finally i want to get a result such that `'(a b c)`, however i get a result such that      `'((a) (b) (c))` how can i fix this problem? i have searched but i couldn't find good solution.

my little code like that not all of them.

```
(append  res  (func x))
(append  res  (func y))
(append  res  (func z))
```

my code like this

```
(define (check a )  
'(1)
)

(define bos '())
(define (func a)
(let loop1([a a] [res '()]) 
(cond 
[(eq? a '()) res] 
[else (let ([ x (check (car a))]) 
(loop1 (cdr a) (append  res (list x)))
)]
)
))
```

Comment: Please post a minimal working example to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: edited. i edit my code, my check func some times returns an element sometimes returns a list, but i dont want to parantheses. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (func a)
  (let loop1 ([a a] [res '()])
    (cond 
      [(eq? a '()) res]
      [else
       (let ([ x (check (car a))]) 
         (loop1 (cdr a) (append res x)))])))
```

Notice that the only change I made (besides improving the formatting) was substituting `(list x)` with `x`. That will do the trick! Alternatively, but less portable - you can use `append*` instead of `append`:

```
(append* res (list x))
```

As a side comment, you should use `(null? a)` for testing if the list is empty. Now if we test the procedure using the sample code in the question, we'll get:

```
(func '(a b c))
=> '(1 1 1)
```

Comment: `append*` isn't included in all Schemes, and your usage is equivalent to `(append res x)` anyway.

Comment: @IstvanChung fair enough, it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that instead of

```
(loop1 (cdr a) (cdr b) c (append  res (list x)))
```

you want

```
(loop1 (cdr a) (cdr b) c (append  res x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the trick is to use `cons` instead of `list`. Imagine `(list 1 2 3 4)` which is the same as `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 '()))))`. Do you see how each part is `(cons this-iteration-element (recurse-further))` like this:

```
(define (make-list n)
  (if (zero? n)
      '()
      (cons n (make-list (sub1 n)))))

(make-list 10) ; ==> (10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

Usually when you can choose direction you can always make it tail recursive with an accumulator:

```
(define (make-list n)
  (let loop ((x 1) (acc '()))
    (if (> x n)
        acc
        (loop (add1 x) (cons x acc))))) ; build up in reverse!


(make-list 10) ; ==> (10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1)
```

Now this is a generic answer. Applied to your working code:

```
(define (func a)
  (let loop1 ([a a] [res '()]) 
    (cond 
      [(eq? a '()) (reverse res)] 
      [else 
       (let ([x (check (car a))]) 
         (loop1 (cdr a) (cons (car x) res)))])))

(func '(a b c)) ; ==> (1 1 1)
```

`append` replaces the `cons` so why not put the `car` og your result to the rest of the list. Since you want the result in order I `reverse` the result in the base case. (can't really tell from the result, but I guessed since you ise `append`)